# Looking for a symbol (arrow with dot)

Tags: symbols, arrows

I am looking for this symbol:

[image]

I recently discovered it in a paper. However, I was not able to find it in the "Comprehensive List" (`symbols-a4.pdf`) or anywhere else.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: I tried all of the steps mentioned there, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen this symbol, but you can easily build one very similar. This is my approach in text mode:
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\newcommand{\arrowdot}{\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{0.1em}%
\hspace{-1em}\textbullet{}%
\raisebox{-.2em}{\textifsymbol[ifgeo]{116}}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdotdot}{\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{0.1em}%
\hspace{-1.5em}\textbullet{}\textbullet{}%
\raisebox{-.2em}{\textifsymbol[ifgeo]{116}}
}


\begin{document}

\textbackslash{\tt arrowdot~~~} \arrowdot

\textbackslash{\tt arrowdotdot} \arrowdotdot
\vspace{3ex}

Subway \arrowdot Airport \arrowdotdot Railway

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very close to what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 8):

This could be what you're looking for:

```
\newcommand{\todot}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\vcenter{
    \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}}$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\longtodot}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\vcenter{
   \hbox{$\mkern6mu\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}}$\hfil\cr$\longrightarrow$\cr}
  }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! This gives me an idea on how to achieve it. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, but if someone wants to use this and finds the spacing around the operator a bit big, you can replace \mathrel with \mathbin, which seems to give it the same spacing as \to.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the usual *overkill*  option of `tikz` which then gives you all the flexibility inherent in `tikz`.  Here are a few of the possible options where you can easily control the location of the  dot (`pos=<percent>`), arrow length (`x=<length>`), arrow type, and color:

[image]

### Further Enhancements

- If desired this could be enhanced to provide separate draw options for the arrow and the dot.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrowdot}[1][]{% #1 = optional draw paramaters (applies to both arrow and dot)
    \mathrel{%
        \tikz [x=0.75cm, y=\heightof{\strut}, line width=.2ex, ->, baseline, #1] 
            \draw (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4) 
            node [pos=0.4,shape=circle, fill=black, draw, inner sep=1pt, #1] {};
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    $A \arrowdot B$
    
    $A \arrowdot[pos=0.5, -latex, x=1.2cm] B$
    
    $A \arrowdot[pos=0.6,red,->] B$
    
    $A \arrowdot[pos=0.2,blue, -stealth] B$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any symbol, you can find it on this pattern recognition machine! It is really awesome!!!

[You can find it here](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Just draw your symbol on the white window and voila!!!

Comment: I tried dtexify and it did not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `chemfig` manual have also an interesting example of arrows with dots:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

% Example from chemfig manual, page 58
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf

\makeatletter
\definearrow4{-.>}{%
\edef\pt@radius{\ifx\@empty#4\@empty 2pt\else #4\fi}% dot radius
\CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF@full](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)
coordinate[midway](mid@point);
\filldraw(mid@point)circle(\pt@radius);%
\CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}{#2}{0.5}{-}{\CF@arrow@end@node}
}
\makeatother


\schemestart
A \arrow{-.>} B \arrow{-.>[above][below][][1pt]} C \arrow{-.>[][below]}[30] D \arrow{-.>[above][][5pt][1.5pt]} E
\schemestop

\end{document}
```